# Python Web Crawler not printing any result

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am trying to create a simple Web Crawler in Python, and when I'm running it it's showing no errors but it's also not printing any results as intended.
I've put my current code below, could anyone please point me in the direction of the problem?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def stepashka_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = "http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/#/page/" + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for resoult in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "video-title"}):
            href = resoult.get(href)
            print(href)
        page += 1

stepashka_spider(1)
```

Comment: Take a look at the format guides and reformat your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Perhaps `soup.findAll` isn't finding anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"video-title"` is in a div tag, you also need to pass a string `"href"`:

```
def stepashka_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = "http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/#/page/" + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for resoult in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "video-title"}):
            a_tag = resoult.a
            print(a_tag["href"])
        page += 1

stepashka_spider(1)
```

Output:

```
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/komedii/37878-klub-grust.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/dramy/37875-kadr.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/multfilmy/37874-betmen-protiv-robina.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/fantastika/37263-hrustalnye-cherepa.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/dramy/34369-bozhiy-syn.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/trillery/37873-horoshee-ubiystvo.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/trillery/34983-zateryannaya-reka.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/priklucheniya/37871-totem-volka.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/fantastika/35224-zheleznaya-shvatka.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/dramy/37870-bercy.html
```

You are actually using the wrong url format, we can also use range instead of a loop:

```
def stepashka_spider(max_pages):
    for page in range(1,max_pages+1):
        url = "http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/page/{}/".format(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        print("Movies for page {}".format(page))
        for resoult in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "video-title"}):
            a_tag = resoult.a
            print(a_tag["href"])
        print()
```

Output:

```
Movies for page 1
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/dramy/37895-raskop.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/semejnyj/36275-domik-v-serdce.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/dramy/35371-enni.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/trillery/37729-igra-na-vyzhivanie.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/trillery/37893-vosstavshie-mertvecy.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/semejnyj/30104-sedmoy-syn-seventh-son-2013-treyler.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/dramy/37892-sekret-schastya.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/uzhasy/37891-davayte-poohotimsya.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/multfilmy/3404-specagent-archer-archer-archer-2010-2013.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/trillery/37334-posledniy-reys.html

Movies for page 2
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/komedii/37890-top-5.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/komedii/37889-igra-v-doktora.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/dramy/36651-vrozhdennyy-porok.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/komedii/37786-superforsazh.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/fantastika/35003-voshozhdenie-yupiter.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/sport/37888-ufc-on-fox-15-machida-vs-rockhold.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/semejnyj/37558-prizrak.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/boeviki/36865-mordekay.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/dramy/37884-stanovlenie-legendy.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/trillery/37883-tainstvo.html

Movies for page 3
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/dramy/37551-nochnoy-beglec.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/dramy/37763-mech-drakona.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/trillery/36471-paren-po-sosedstvu.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/dramy/36652-amerikanskiy-snayper.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/dramy/37555-feniks.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/semejnyj/35156-gnezdo-drakona-vosstanie-chernogo-drakona.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/kriminal/37882-ch-b.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/priklucheniya/37881-admiral-bitva-za-men-ryan.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/trillery/37880-malyshka.html
http://online.stepashka.com/filmy/trillery/36417-poteryannyy-ray.html
```

Comment: Padraic Cunningham  thank you very much for that answer!! i have another question ) i understand the "div" part you have added to the code, but i don't quiet understand the "href = resoult.h2" part and the line after it "print(href.a["href"])"

Comment: Beaten to it!  Was just typing that up when I saw the answer come in.

Comment: Watch your spelling: `href = resoult.get(href)`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. one last question: "a_tag" is a var for "resoult.a" but what is the ""resoult.a" ?

Comment: resoult is each  div with a `"video-title"` tag, `resoult.a` is the `a` tag in each div. if you print resoult  you will see exactly what is happening

Comment: Hello once more, i have another problem in my web crawler: when i set the number of pages to 2 or 3 it just gets the link of the 1st page 2-3 times, it wont crawl to the next page!?  any ideas?

Comment: I will have a look later and see what the issue is

Comment: Padraic Cunningham i think i have found the problem, in my code the "Page = 1", so when i run the program it is adding the "str(page)" but the link is ending with "/" so basicly i need some way to add "/1,/2,/3..." to the url at each loop, so i think i need to change the "page=1" to something like page = /1  but i don't know how to do it, or something like that...

Comment: so you want all the movie links from each page?

Comment: Basically yes, I want it to loop through the the amount of pages I give it, and get all the links, I have no problems with sites that have in their links '' =1,2...'' at the end, but in that site the ending of the link is different